# MySQL Query Result bind to Another Query as a Object Array

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

[image]

Hi, I want to get this result as the object array in another query. I want to display this another query result single column. `[{'ID':437, 'OrderId':255, 'TimesTamp':'2021-12-15'},{'ID':438, 'OrderId':255, 'TimesTamp':'2021-12-15'},...]` like this. Does anyone have an idea about that? Thank You

Comment: `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(...))`

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG can be used if you are using an upper version of MySQL

Comment: SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(OrderID,ID)) FROM orderattempt WHERE OrderID=255;

Did you mean by like this? it is not working. I used latest version in MySql

Comment: *it is not working* Please study the functions descriptions and investigate code exampled in the Reference Manual, especially JSON_OBJECT(). Then build synthactically correct query.